# How can i install 'ical' package in Node js in AWS Lambda?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, calendar, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a function for Alexa skill for reminders. I already wrote the Lambda function for that including ical declaration but whenever I execute that code it shows 'ical' module is not defined. Please can you give any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this steps to use npm packages in your lambda function.

- Create a new folder for your application in your local machine. Ex. my-app
- Add all your Javascript files and package.json.
- Include all you npm dependencies in **package.json**
- Install all npm modules using npm install. All node modules will be installed and **npm_modules** folder will be created inside your project.
- Zip your complete project folder (my-app.zip)
- Upload your zip file in aws lambda console
- Finally execute your test & run your lamdba function.

Comment: Thank you Ashok JayaPrakash . But i didn't get "Edit code inline" for modifications in some alexa developer intents functions in Lambda code. How can i clear that problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your project with new changes needs to be re uploaded with the above mentioned steps. You cannot Edit code inline when its in zip format.